# Basement tie rods leaking after repair

Tags: concrete, basement, waterproofing

I'm preparing the basement concrete walls before finishing the basement. I will be gluing XPS insulation and building a drywall wall without added vapor barrier.

The previous owners appear to have had a tie rod repair done, and I haven't seen any issues with most points. As far as I can tell, the repair was just hydraulic cement without urethane or the like. One point occasionally has water seeping very slowly - the surface of the wall is wet to the touch but no visible running water, and there is no puddling on the floor, just a bit more dampness.

What sorts of additional repairs (if any) should I do before finishing the wall? Redoing the hydraulic cement (with or without chipping out the existing)? A surface coating like drylok or an epoxy? Something more intrusive?

[image: A portion of concrete wall with a filled tie rod point. It is slowly seeping water]

Comment: The tie rods are leftover from the formwork...if they're rusting, it may mean you have water sitting on the outside of the wall.